# Access individual values from JSON array in PHP?

Tags: php, json

My PHP page looks like this:

```
$bannertext = $_GET['bannertext'];
$banner = json_decode($bannertext);
```

How do I access each of those strings now? Like `echo $banner[1];` and so on?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: what is the value of bannertext?

Comment: bannertext is an array consisting of 3  test strings.

Answer (score 0):

That depends, what is the value of `$banner`? Use `var_dump($banner)`.

`json_decode` will return `null` if it can't parse the data.

Comment: well `$bannertext` should be made of 3 different text strings. And I tried `var_dump($banner)` and it returned `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use echo $banner[1], $banner has to be an array.

You can use explode for that:

$banner = explode(' ', $bannertext);

echo $banner[1];